# Adding list item is not adding all innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

for part of a learning project I'm making I've run into a weird javascript/html issue. The section in question is a simple to do list, which works perfectly fine *except* for one thing. The program will successfully grab the text the user enters, add it to a new list item and insert it into the unordered list, but only adds an X (for a remove function I haven't added yet) to the first element.

Additionally, if you check in the browser inspector, both new li's do have the 'a' element with the X inside of it, but on hovering over the a element in both li's (or more li's depending) they all "point" back to the one and only 'a' element on the first li.

Can anyone explain what I did wrong so that I can fix it and avoid this in the future? Why is it not adding the 'a' element individually to each new li?

I've included a jsfiddle link below:

```
 const li = document.createElement('li');
  // add li class
  li.className = 'list-item';
  // append text node containing user input to li item
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskList.value));
  // create 'a' element to list and add classes/html
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.className = 'delete-item';
  link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';

  // append 'a' element to li
  li.appendChild(link);
  document.querySelector('.list-items').append(li);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Iahon/xocpb6n7/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code works, it's a CSS issue.

Your `.delete-item` class has a `position: absolute` property that makes all the links to be stacked at the same position. Change your `position: absolute` with a `float: right` and remove the `top` and `right` properties:

```css
.container .row2 .to-doList .list-items .list-item .delete-item {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This will fix the issue and keep your link at the same position.

Edit: If you do not want to use `float: right`, see @AdamKniec answer below offering another possibility by modifying the CSS of the parent element.

Comment: Source please ?

Comment: Thank you, I changed the position absolute to float:right and it works now.

What might I use instead of float:right in this case?

Comment: We have much more elegant  alternatives coming from Flexbox I guess

Comment: I'm standing to my position that for this example `float: right` is the right choice and prevents the use of flexboxes just to put a link on the right. Not the most recent does not necessarily means bad practice.

Comment: position:absolute was used there so instead of using ugly float, we can simply position the list item relatively. Much better solution I guess

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly to your newly edited answer, which now provides a solution. Both answers are, to me, correct. And you obvisouly got something agains the float property, that I'm not going to try to understand. Now users have both methods as choice.

Comment: I'm fine with that. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

It works but your styles complicated that. Look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kedao6xm/

I removed the `position:absolute` from `.container .row2 .to-doList .list-items .list-item .delete-item`

You need to careful with that css property. All of your elements were added correctly but they were placed in the exact same position :)

EDIT: Look at the above link please one more time:
X is now aligned without the `float:right`.

Your X is still positioned as `absolute` but the list item has `position:relative` which fixes the issue :)

Comment: Thank you! As for the complicated CSS, I'm trying to learn SASS too. Might be nesting these a little too much!

Comment: Great :) I'm glad I could help. Good luck

Comment: I made an edit to the link. Take a look. Your X is now positioned correctly